# Curve Plot logistic regression

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

here is my model. Exam_taken is a binary variable (0,1), and social class (1-10 scale) and GDP are continuous variables.

```
fit<-glm(Exam_taken~Gender+Social_class*GDP, data=final, family=binomial(link="probit")
summary(fit)
```

I need to draw graphs. Goal 1) the relationship between Social_class and Exam_taken; Goal 2) the interaction of Social_class*GDP on Exam_taken.

I encountered two problems.

1. I used the following code for Goal 1:

```
#exclude missing values
final=subset(final, final$Social_class!="NA")
final=subset(final, final$Exam_taken!="NA")
#graph
library(popbio)
logi.hist.plot(final$Social_class, final$Exam_taken, boxp=FALSE, type = "hist")
```

I got an error "Error in seq.default(min(independ),max(independ),len=100):'from' must be a finite number"
How to fix it? Thank you so much

2. I have no idea how to draw the interaction with two continuous variables on a binary outcome. Can anyone provide some directions? Thanks!

Comment: We'd be happy to help, but without some data, it's difficult to see how we can.

Comment: Nothing is ever "==" to NA, likewise nothing is ever "!=" NA. Learn to use `is.na()`. (Also learn to use subset properly. Do NOT use "$" to refer to column names.) It's not clear that either of these issues are leading to your error, but they should be addressed. And show what efforts you have used to find how to plot interactions. Surely there are example on the web or in SO. https://www.google.com/search?q=r+glm+interaction+plot&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS779US779&oq=r+glm+interaction+plot&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.7747j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

It can be difficult to represent a regression involving three dependent variables, since it is effectively a four-dimensional structure. However, since one of the variables (Gender) has only two levels, and Social class has 10 discrete levels, we can display the model using color scales and facets. First we create a data frame with all combinations of Gender and Social class at every value of GDP from, say, $1000 to $100,000

```r
pred_df <- expand.grid(Gender = c("Male", "Female"),
                       Social_class = 1:10,
                       GDP = 1:100 * 1000)
```

Now we get the probability of taking the exam at each combination:

```r
pred_df$fit  <- predict(fit, newdata = pred_df, type = "response")
```

We can then plot the model predictions like so:

```r
ggplot(pred_df, aes(GDP, fit, colour = Social_class, group = Social_class)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Gender~.) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, limits = c(0, 1e5)) +
  labs(y = "Probability of taking exam",
       color = "Social class") +
  scale_color_viridis_c(breaks = 1:10) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(barheight = unit(50, "mm")))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, but we can make a reasonable replica given clues from your description and code.

```r
set.seed(1)

final <- data.frame(Gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), 100),
                    Social_class = sample(10, 200, TRUE),
                    GDP = 1000 * sample(20:60, 200, TRUE))

final$Exam_taken <- rbinom(200, 1, 
                           c(0, 0.1) + 0.05 * final$Social_class +
                             final$GDP/1e5 - 0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sjPlot` package to plot the predicted values from the model. If you save the output of the `plot_model()` function, you can modify its appearance  using `ggplot2`.

Here is one of many pages that can show you other options with this package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_model_estimates.html

```
library(sjPlot)

plot_model(fit, type = "int")
```