# Plotting a Binomial GLM using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have created the following Binomial GLM model and wish to plot it using ggplot. The issue i am having is how I plot multiple variables as the x and y axis.

notUsing, using are being predicted using age + education + wantsMore here. How do i add these as arguments into the aes() of ggplot as there are multiple variables?

This should be clearer below.

model created;

```
my_model = glm(cbind(notUsing, using) ~ age + education + wantsMore,
           data = contraceptive2,
           family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

plotting the model; (Hopefully this will make it easier to see where i am failing. I need to replay the x and y for my data, but as they contain multiple variables i dont know how to do this)

```
#make predictions
my_model_preds = predict(my_model, contraceptive2,  se.fit = TRUE, type = 'response')

#ggplot of the model
ggplot(contraceptive2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x, my_model_preds), col = 'blue')
```

part of data if needed;

```
head(contraceptive2)
    age education wantsMore notUsing using
1   <25       low       yes       53     6
2   <25       low        no       10     4
3   <25      high       yes      200    52
4   <25      high        no       50    10
5 25-29       low       yes       60    14
6 25-29       low        no       19    10
7  25-29      high       yes      155    54
8  25-29      high        no       65    27
9  30-39       low       yes      112    33
10 30-39       low        no       77    80
11 30-39      high       yes      118    46
12 30-39      high        no       68    78
13 40-49       low       yes       35     6
14 40-49       low        no       46    48
15 40-49      high       yes        8     8
16 40-49      high        no       12    31
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Is `geom_smooth(method = "glm", ...)` an option?

Comment: there are no columns named `x` or `y` in `contraceptive2`?

Comment: @Langtang Yeh this is my issue, i obviously need to replace x and y with what they should be, but i dont know how to do this and both x and y are made up of multiple variables

Comment: You need to decide what you want to put on the x-axis.. The `my_model_preds$fit` contains the predicted probability of notUsing.

Comment: @langtang ah ok, so i basically just plot my model predictions as usual on the y axis and choose one of the variables to plot on the x ? or am i putting my_model_preds$fit on the x here?

Comment: @Joe, you need to decide what you are trying to communicate with your plot first, and then decide how to plot it. The former is more important than the latter.

Comment: @Joe [here's a recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418257/curve-plot-logistic-regression/72418662#72418662) showing how to plot three independent variables in a logistic regression. If you struggle to apply this to your own data, please edit your question to include your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the supplied data, we can see that, because two of your independent variables are binary, it is possible to plot the whole model using error bars with facets and colors:

```r
df <- with(contraceptive2,
     expand.grid(age = unique(age), education = unique(education),
                 wantsMore = unique(wantsMore)))

fits <- predict(my_model, newdata = df, se.fit = TRUE)

# Get odds from modrl
df$prediction <- exp(fits$fit) 
df$upper <- exp(fits$fit + 1.96 * fits$se.fit)
df$lower <- exp(fits$fit - 1.96 * fits$se.fit)

# Convert odds to probabilities
df$prediction <- df$prediction / (1 + df$prediction)
df$upper <- df$upper / (1 + df$upper)
df$lower <- df$lower / (1 + df$lower)

# Plot probabilities
ggplot(df, aes(age, prediction)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, colour = wantsMore), 
                width = 0.25, size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = wantsMore), shape = 21, size = 3, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  facet_grid(~education) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Probability of not using", limits = c(0, 1),
                     labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  `broom::augment` could (I think) get you the predictions and CIs slightly more compactly.